How to query using inline JSX conditional expression using Firebase?
I googled but couldn't find a similar usage. Maybe the question is very specific but I wonder if I can write an inline conditional JSX expression using firebase like this way or somewhat similar to this?
let querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "users"), 
    where(targetChosen === "town" ? ("town", "==", user.town) : targetChosen === "city" ? ("city", "==", user.city) :  targetChosen === "country" && ("country", "==", user.country) ),
    where("gender", "==", genderChosen),
    orderBy("rating", "desc"),
    limit(10)
))

Here an error comes:

function where() called with invalid data.
Unsupported field value: undefined.

EDIT: user is an object having fields { id: string, name: string, town: string, city: string, country: string }. targetChosen is a local variable (not depending on user object) and also a string which is one of the strings of "town", "city" or "country". genderChosen is one of the strings of "female" or "name". (it works without any problem with JSX expression when used as variable inside firebase function). The targetChosen string value is changing according to 3 buttons with titles of "town", "city" and "country". Whenever one of them clicked, targetChosen string value changes. Its structure can be changed for this aim in the question to be done, maybe translating it to a 3 itemed array for the firebase code to work.

No, you can't pass JSX expressions to Firestore as it doesn't know how to execute them. But I'm not sure if that's actually what's happening here. What is the value of user, genderChosen and targetChosen when this code executes? Most likely, one of them does not have a value.

@FrankvanPuffelen value of user is an object {id: ... name: ... etc}. Value of genderChosen is string of "female" and "male". Value of targetChosen are all strings. I checked again and all are defined. Even if there is no undefined value here, then the code nevertheless will not execute? This is JS format, embedded inside firebase functions

Don't describe it in words in a comment please, but edit your question to show the exact data in a way that allows us to copy/paste/run it.

@FrankvanPuffelen Ok, I am editing the question now

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply ?

As Frank said in comments, you can't use a JSX expression like this.  where requires exactly three arguments, and you need to provide them in the way that JavaScript requires, just like any function call.  For your case, it could go something like this, since targetChosen always matches the name of the field filter, as well as the name of the property of the user object:
...
where(targetChosen, "==", user[targetChosen]),
...

If for some reason you can no longer make the stated assumptions, and have to write some conditional based on the value of targetChosen, maybe you'll have to use a switch on the value of targetChosen to determine the values to pass to where.

Ok, I tested it now, it works, now telling that new index needs to be created: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/p.... Now, I think I should create 3 new indexes for the 3 of the alternative targetChosen values, right?

An index must exist to support every distinct query kind of query.  I suggest reviewing the documentation about that.
